# Cartesian Product is Countably Infinite by Induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Suppose we want to show that a Cartesian product of the form $B^n$ of $n$ copies of the natural numbers is countably infinite. The proof with just two copies of the natural numbers is a standard Cantor diagonalization argument, but I don't understand the inductive step of this proof, which seems to be that $B^{k+1} = B^k \times B$, and since the Cartesian product of two copies of the naturals is countably infinite, this Cartesian product of two countably infinite sets is also countable.

This doesn't seem very convincing. Wouldn't we need an additional lemma to say that the Cartesian product of two countably infinite sets, regardless of how many items are accounted for in their Cartesian product, is also countably infinite? Or do we create a bijection from $B^k$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and $B$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and then show countability by function composition? This doesn't seem like a very difficult proof, but it seems that there's a jump in the logic.

Comment: "Or do we create a bijection from $B^k$ to ℕ and $B$ to ℕ and then show countability by function composition?" Yes, that is what you do if you feel better doing that. But there is no real need, countable is countable and $B^k$ shouldn't feel bigger than $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I think that's certainly more intuitive, but I suppose my main concern is: is it sufficient to say "these two sets are countable, so by the n = 2 case (the basis for induction), the induction step holds?"

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly rigorous.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. One more question if you wouldn't mind. Obviously the rules of exponents lets us write, say, $x^{n+1} = x^n \cdot x$. Is this necessarily true for the Cartesian product, as well? My professor presented the argument by writing out the product and grouping together the first $k$ copies of the naturals. I don't want to make any unwarranted assumptions, but it seems like this is a fairly sensible, general principle of the Cartesian product.

Comment: It is true for the Cartesian product *to some extent*, let me show you in an answer to have a better display.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your last question.

The Cartesian product of two sets is a set of couples $$A\times B=\{(a,b)\ | a\in A, b\in B\}$$

The Cartesian product of three sets is a set of triples defined similarly
$$A\times B\times C=\{(a,b, c)\ | a\in A, b\in B, c\in C\}$$

Therefore there is a slight conceptual difference between, say $(A\times B)\times C$ and $A\times B\times C$: an element in the former will look like $$((a, b), c)$$
which is really a couple (whose first element is a couple itself) and not **equal** to the triple $(a,b,c)$.

Yet there is a natural identification between the two sets (which is even an isomorphism for most of the classical algebraic structures) and in general we omit to mention it since it is harmless for most purposes.